# Selecting based on condition having multiple options

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, aggregate

I'm totally confused about using aggregate functions after where clause or anywhere after mentioning the table_name

EMP Table as posted on http://viditkothari.co.in/post/27045365558/sql-commands-1

Query Info:
**Display all the emp who have sal equal to any of the emp of deptno 30**

Suggested query:

```
select * 
  from employee_4521 
 where sal having (select sal 
                     from employee_4521 
                    where deptno = 30);
```

Returns following error:

> ERROR at line 1:
>   ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

with an asterik marked under 'h' of having clause

Comment: If you need to ask a second question, feel free to create a second thread.  It complicates things if you ask multiple unrelated questions in a thread.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't appear to be any reason to use an aggregate function here.  Just use an `IN` or an `EXISTS`

```
select * 
  from employee_4521 
 where sal in (select sal 
                 from employee_4521 
                where deptno=30);
```

or

```
select * 
  from employee_4521 a
 where exists( select 1
                 from employee_4521 b
                 where b.deptno = 30
                   and a.sal = b.sal );
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution, but I do not understand the purpose of **1** in the 2nd solution, after **select** subquery.

Comment: A friend of mine suggested this :  
select * from employee_4521 where sal=any(select sal from employee_4521 where deptno=30);  

Is this correct ?

Comment: @viditkothari - Using `ANY` would be unconventional but would be essentially identical to the `IN` version of the query.  The `1` in the `EXISTS` query is irrelevent-- you could select anything you want there.  The `EXISTS` clause just checks whether at least one row is returned by the subquery.  You can select anything you'd like there.